# Visual Studio 2013 crashes when writing opening angle bracket

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, crash, intellisense, xamarin.forms

everytime I try to write an opening angle bracket in vs13 it crashes.

The Problem only happens in a xamarin.forms project and in an xaml-file.
Every other key works fine, just the opening angle bracket causes the problem.
If I copy/paste it in the code it works fine, as well... but this can't be the solution...

Version: VS Premium 2013 - 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

I am using Xamarin for Visual Studio Version: 3.11.586 and XAML Styler in version: 1.5.

Comment: Try disabling the XAML Styler and/or any other plug-ins you might have and try again. Try disabling them one by one and check if there is any improvement.

Comment: already done, doesn't work. But i found the solution. There was a hidden file in my projectdir, which was name <solutionname>.suo and all i had to do was deleting this file and restart vs. everything works now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by deleting the hidden file .suo in the projectdir. After a restart everything works fine! :)